# JQuery traversing table column

Tags: jquery, count, html-table, row, traversal

I have a table as follows;

```
<table>
<tr>
<th scope="col"></th>
<th scope="col">Column One</th>
<th scope="col">Column Two</th>
<th scope="col">Column Three</th>
<th scope="col">Column Four</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Row One</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Row Two</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="click"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Row Three</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Row Four</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="target"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

I would like to be able to click on the `<td>` with a class of 'click' and then alert me as to how many rows away the `<td>` with a class of target is. (in the above example it would return 2).

There may be other `<td>` elements in the table with a class of target. I am only interested in the number of rows until the *next* target in the same row as my 'clicked' `td`. Any targets above my 'clicked' `<td>` or in other columns should be ignored.

If there are no other 'target' `<td>`'s after the clicked element in the same row, the alert should read 'no other targets'.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: So what is your question? What have you already done yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
var targetRowIndex = $('.target')[0].parentNode.rowIndex;

$(".click").bind("click",function(){
   alert( targetRowIndex - this.parentNode.rowIndex ); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BZDyr/3/

You can probably implement the rest of the precise functionality yourself if you realize what's going on in that code.

Comment: Hi, This is really close, however, targetRowIndex always returns the first element with a class of '.target' in the table. I need it to only return the index of the *next* element with a class of '.target' that is in the same table column as '.click'

Comment: @user469453, yes I didn't make code that you can directly copy paste. That's why it says `You can probably implement the rest of the precise functionality yourself if you realize what's going on in that code.`. I am simply showing you how you can retrieve the `rowIndex` with a simple example, not creating your application. :) Hint: the `targetRowIndex` is static and `[0]` means the first element with class `.target`. :P

Comment: Hi Esailija, Thats great thanks - is there a way i can find the column index also (i tried the obvious of changing rowIndex to colIndex)?

Comment: @user469453 yes `td` elements have `.cellIndex`. Note that `.rowIndex` is actually got from `tr` element, (the `td` element's `.parentNode`). So to get the row index = `this.parentNode.rowIndex` and column index = `this.cellIndex`

Comment: @user469453 you may find this useful http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/table_access.html

Answer (score 1):

you could probably find a solution using a combination of [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), along with siblings, next, previous, etc. basically using the traversal methods to select `"td.target"`